# Return a field as object or as primitive type in JSON in a REST API?

Tags: json, rest, api

Currently I'm working on a REST API with an object that has a status. Should I return the status as a string or as an object?
When is it smart to change from field being a primitive type to a field being an object?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1
        "name": "Hello"
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "id": 1
        "name": "Hello"
        "status": {
                   "id": 0
                   "name": "active"
                  }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In terms of [extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility) I would suggest going for and object.

Using an object also adds the advantage of being able to split responsibility in terms of identifying (via f.e. an `id` field) and describing (via f.e. a `name` or `description` field), in your case, a status.

Adding i18n as a possible necessity, an object would also have to carry a string as identifier.

All these things are not possible with simple primitives. Conclusion: go for an object.

Other interesting remarks are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8643308/4058449).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you need to pass.

If you only want to distinguish between different states and have all other related information (strings, translations, images) on the client either way, you might only want to send a simple integer value and use an enum on the client side. This reduces the data to the smallest amount.

If you have data that changes within one status on the server side, you need an object to pass everything else.

But best practice here would be to reduce data as much as possible.