# Why does the delete operator deletes a function constructor?

Tags: javascript

[In this post,](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/5-facts-about-delete-operator-in-javascript-c16fd2588cd)
It says that the delete operator does not work on functions.

> The invocation of the delete operator returns true when it emoves a property and false otherwise. it’s only effective on an object’s properties, it has no effect on variable or function names.

But consider this code:

```
delete Date;
new Date(); // thros an reference error
```

To make sure that Date is a function constructor, I wrote:

```
typeof Date; // "function"
```

This piece of code verifies that Date is a constructor, not an object. If the delete operator work on this particular type of function constructor, it should work on my constructor also. But it doesn't.

```
function a(){}
var b = new a();
delete a; // false
```

So, the delete operator did not delete my function constructor but for some reason, it deleted the Date constructor. Can someone clear this confusion of mine?

Comment: The article says _“It’s only effective on an object’s properties, it has no effect on variable or function names.”_. You’ve misinterpreted that: the difference isn’t between functions and non-functions. The difference is between properties and variables. Function declarations behave like variables. `Date` is a property on `window`. See [`delete`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), [JavaScript Variables vs Properties](/q/32491231/4642212), [Is there any difference between a global variable and a property of the Global Object](/q/12439256/4642212).

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in a browser context then `Date` is a property on `window`, which is what you actually deleted. That the value of that property is a constructor/function doesn't really matter, the property is gone and most likely that was your only reference to that function.

This still works and returns a date object.

```
var dateFn = Date;
delete Date;
new dateFn();
```

Because it was only the property that was removed and not the actual function.

Comment: Subsequently (to close the loop), `delete dateFn` returns false - the **has no effect on variable or function names** part.

Comment: @Toby—because the *Date* property of the *window* object was removed, not the Date function/object itself. You might not be aware of the difference between primitives and objects, see [*object vs. primitive*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643276/object-vs-primitive), read multiple answers.

Comment: @Karl-Johan Sjögren, the Date property is in the window object, not Window. console.log(Window.Date)// returns undefined.

Comment: @Toby in the future, feel free to make an edit when you see a clear typo.

Comment: @VLAZ, it won't let me at that time; it just gives me this message:"Suggested edit queue is full".